# Get dxdiag results using java

Tags: java

```
                String filePath = "./results.txt";

                // Use "dxdiag /t" variant to redirect output to a given file
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","dxdiag","/t",filePath);
                System.out.println("-- Executing dxdiag command --");
                Process p = pb.start();
                p.waitFor();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                String line;
                System.out.println(String.format("-- Printing %1$1s info --",filePath));
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

                    if(line.trim().startsWith("Card name:")
                       || line.trim().startsWith("Current Mode:")
                       || line.trim().startsWith("Display Memory:"))

                        textArea_3.append(line.trim() + "\n");

                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The error that I get is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\results.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at gui.Gui$4.actionPerformed(Gui.java:136)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

I've tried it on Win7 (does not work) and on Win8(it works as expected). If anyone has a thought on what's going on I'd greatly appreciate the help, thx.

Comment: Could you perhaps add some code such that the code you posted becomes a minimal runnable program that shows off the problem? Right now it seems as if you copied it from a method body which contains an initial try keyword as well as a definition for the user interface.

Comment: In terms of your problem, it seems to be a relative path problem. I'd recommend trying to add the line System.out.println(new File(filePath).getAbsolutePath()); before instantiating the buffered reader to see where exactly the system tries to look for the results file. You might also want to specify the output location for DXDIAG as an absolute path to ensure the results are stored where you want them to.

Comment: I've set the path to the tmp dir and it works now thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a relative path problem. I'd recommend trying to add the line System.out.println(new File(filePath).getAbsolutePath()); before instantiating the buffered reader to see where exactly the system tries to look for the results file. You might also want to specify the output location for DXDIAG as an absolute path to ensure the results are stored where you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

**1st** complete your code your class name missing.

**2nd** give main method `public static void main(String args[])`.

**3rd** take try block.

And **4th** last one create TextArea object which is missing in your code :`TextArea textArea_3 = new TextArea();`

Code will work.